# making factorial code with python what's the problem,?

Tags: python, factorial

```
def factorial(n):
    if (n>1):
        return n* factorial(n-1)
```

```
def factorial(n):
    if (n>1):
        return n* factorial(n-1)
    else:
        return 1
```

The first code has an error but the second function runs properly
what is the difference between the two programs?
what is the problem with the first code?
thank you

Comment: the problem in the first function is that if `n` is 1 or smaller, then it returns `None` and you cant multiply `None` by a number

Comment: *"what is the difference between two code*" The difference is very clear. The first returns `None` if the condition  is false, the second returns 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that when the first code evaluates for `n<=1`, there is no returned value. This causes the function to (by default) return `None`. Now while evaluating for 2, the program says

```
return n* factorial(n-1)
```

That is equivalent to;

```
return 2*None #Since factorial(1)=None
```

Hence It gives an error as `NoneType` cannot be multiplied by an integer